# find the top k elements of this sequence

Tags: algorithm

If there is a set of n positive integers (n < = 200000), 2 ^ n-1 nonempty subsets of the set are sorted by the sum of the elements of each subset. Find the first k  (k < = n) sets in this sequence, and output their elements sum in turn. Ask the algorithm of O (n) or O (nlogn) time complexity of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to sort the array.

Then, we maintain a *set of candidate subsets*, the size of which is equal to `k - i`, if `i` is the number of subsets already found.

The next selected subset corresponds to the subset in this set of candidates with minimum sum.

Then, each time a new solution is added, corresponding to a set `S = {i0, i1, i2}` for example, where the `iu` are indices, then we have to consider as additional candidates all the `S U {j}`, where `j` is an index greater than `i2`, and where `U` means union here.

In practice, we only have to memorize the value of the last index, so `j` here. We also need to keep the corresponding sum value, in order to be able to sort the set of candidates.

We could use a min-heap for this set of candidates. However, to limit the complexity, we need to limit the number of candidates (`k-i`). For that, a min-max heap could be used. As there is not such structure in the C++ standard library, I used a `std::multiset` in the following implementation.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>

struct Subset {
    int sum;
    int index_max;
};

std::vector<int> solution (std::vector<int>& A, int n, int k) {
    auto Comp = [] (const Subset& s0, const Subset& s1) {
        if (s0.sum == s1.sum) {
            return s0.index_max < s1.index_max;
        }
        return s0.sum < s1.sum;
    };
    
    std::sort (A.begin(), A.end());
    
    std::vector<int> sums;
    sums.reserve (k);
    std::multiset<Subset, decltype(Comp)> candidates (Comp);
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
           candidates.insert ({A[i], i});
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        //auto n = Cells.size();
        auto top = candidates.begin();
        auto best = *top;
        candidates.erase (top);
        sums.push_back (best.sum);
        
        if (i == k-1) continue;
        auto last = std::prev(candidates.end());
        auto vmax = (*last).sum;
        
        for (int j = best.index_max + 1; j < k; ++j) {
            int new_sum = best.sum + A[j];
            if (new_sum >= vmax) break;
            candidates.insert({new_sum, j});
            candidates.erase (last);
            last = std::prev(candidates.end());
            vmax = (*last).sum;
        }
    }
    return sums;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> A = {1, 2, 3, 6, 6, 7};
    int n = A.size();
    int k = n;
    auto sums = solution (A, n, k);
    for (int x: sums) {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Complexity :**

Evaluating the complexity theoretically is not easy.

For the first step, sorting is O(n logn).

For the second step, the complexity depends on the number of insertions/deletions in the multiset `candidates`. Each insertion cost O(logk). I could not evaluate the number of insertions theoretically.

I made several benchmarks, for different sizes of `k = n`, and different ranges for values of the data.

I measured that the number of insertions (in the inner `for` loop) is rather stable and about equal to `n log2(n)/2`, except for very low data ranges, for which this value decreases.

Using this measured value, for `n = k`, we get a global complexity of `O(n logn^2)`.

For `n = 200000`, on my PC, it takes about 1 second  each time to get the result.

Comment: thanks for help.  i understand your solution,that is a lot of help.But how can this prove to be a linear complexity or at the worst situation if there is a possibility O(nk)?

Comment: I tried to add some complexity evaluation (not perfect). Moreover, I slightly improved the code `if (new_sum >= vmax) break;` instead of `if (new_sum > vmax) break;`

Comment: That helps me a lot.Thank you very much.